# c++ not able to open child window after closing it

Tags: c++, winapi, window, childwindow

I'm having some problems with my child window. I use a button from the `AppendMenu` to open it, but after I close the child window, I can't open it anymore.

code:

```
WNDCLASSEX chwincl;

chwincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
chwincl.lpszClassName = "Child";
chwincl.lpfnWndProc = ChildProcedure;
chwincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
chwincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
chwincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
chwincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
chwincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
chwincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
chwincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
chwincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
chwincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);

if (!RegisterClassEx(&chwincl))
    return 2;

chwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
    "Child",
    "Add...",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300,
    150,
    HWND_DESKTOP,
    NULL,
    hThisInstance,
    NULL);
```

I open the child window with this:

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_Click) {
        ShowWindow(chwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        UpdateWindow(chwnd);
    }
```

And I close it with this:

```
DestroyWindow(chwnd);
```

Why can I only open my child window once?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a minimal example. Please don't make people read through tons of unnecessary code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would be necessary to see how I create my windows.

Comment: We want to see how you create your windows. However, it is hard to believe that all six grandchild windows are required to demonstrate the problem. I bet you can remove them. Similarly, I bet you can remove the custom paint handler, and the problem will still be there. Keep removing code until you get the smallest program that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Now you deleted too much. You need to produce the smallest complete program that still demonstrates the problem. Your previous attempt missed the "smallest" part of the requirements. Your second attempt missed the "complete program" part of the requirements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed it.

Comment: Still not there. You need a complete program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DestroyWindow` destroys the the window completely. After that call, it no longer exists. So you can't then show it again with `ShowWindow` - you have to actually create it again from scratch.

Instead of calling `DestroyWindow` to hide it, use `ShowWindow(chwnd, SW_HIDE);`

Answer (score 0):

You need the flag `SW_RESTORE` in your `ShowWindow` call when restoring a minimized (or closed) window.